# Meaning of "one that is now reliant on public appeal for help is to be a breakthrough"

Tags: american-english, british-english

There is one more sentence in this video. Source is : https://youtu.be/3prCCJIhIKA?t=145

This is original sentence - **one that is now reliant on public appeal for help is to be a breakthrough**

I could rewrite it in simple speech like this but no understanding at all in terms of what it says -

**one that is now dependent on making a serious request to public is to be a dramatic turn in an incident**.

but what is its meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, that isn't a complete sentence, but a fragment which follows a reference to "the case" (of the disappearance of Madeleine McCann).

Second, you've misheard it: it is

> one that's now reliant on a public appeal for help **if there's to be** a breakthrough.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you explain this in simple speech? I tried to rewrite it but could not understand it,

Comment: Solving the case depends on asking for help from the public.